# How secure is iOS Device ID?

Tags: ios, security

Is there any known way for a hacker to access the Device ID of my iOS application (ID for Vendor)?

Can a server assume if it receives a IDFV over HTTPS that it actually came from the expected device?

Comment: An IDFV is an opaque value; there is no way to validate it, so you can't know whether the string you receive is an IDFV or just some other random string in the same format.  The question you need to ask is how secure is your communication between your app and your server?  A tool like Charles Proxy can be used to intercept that, but you can mitigate this through certificate pinning.

Answer (score 0):

Your server, receiving the IDFV cannot assume anything about the device that made the request. Any parameter, any data in a request is just user input from the perspective of your server, and as such, cannot be trusted.

Anybody can sniff your IDFV from your app communication. HTTPS does not help at all. Certificate pinning would make that somewhat more difficult, but in the worst case your app binary would need to be peeked into or modified - not that difficult at all. After having your IDFV, it would be straightforward to forge requests with that.

The bottomline is, on the server side you can not trust the client, and you also can't prevent somebody making another client if they want. You can make it somewhat harder technically (by implementing obfuscation or certificate pinning), you can also put up legal protections, but it will never be fully secure, if by "being secure" you mean being able to identify your own app.